# How to update Access MDB files - InstallShield?

Tags: database, windows-installer, ms-access-2007, installshield, installshield-2012

I want to add an entry to one of the tables in Access MDB file during installation using an InstallSheild 2012 installer. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why not run code on first open of the database application?

Answer (score 2):

InstallShield natively supposes MSSQL, Oracle and MySQL database connections / script execution.  You'd have to write a custom action to connect to the MDB.

I agree this would be better done outside of the installer.  If someone ever restored an older copy of the MDB ( it is just a file copy after all )  then the changes would be lost.  It's better to handle it on run of the application.